Nginx proxy_pass randomally get timeout error when proxying to same machine through outside server
Disclaimer- I already asked this question in cloudflare forums but after some digging I'm realizing it's more of an nginx issue.
I have example.com domain which runs through cloudflare, and sits at 12.34.56.78
DNS:



Record Type
Name
Content
proxied




A
example.com
12.34.56.78
yes


A
*
12.34.56.78
yes



I also have app1.com which is not running through cloudflare, also sits at 12.34.56.78



Record Type
Name
Content




A
app1.com
12.34.56.78


A
www.app1.com
12.34.56.78



I'm trying to proxy_pass app1.com to app1.example.com so I have this nginx block:
# minimized version
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name app1.com www.app1.com;
    
    location /{
        proxy_pass app1.example.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }
    ssl_certificate /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/deploy/domains/app1.com.cert.combined;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/deploy/domains/app1.com.key;
}

Now if I remove the cloudflare proxied option then app1.com works without any timeout error.
But if I use cloudflare proxy I get randomally timeout error as seen below
What I found out:

If I direct app1.com to a different server, lets say 111.222.333.444 and then use exactly the same nginx block, then it works without timeout errors- timeout errors only occur when both of them in the same server.
So I guess something to do with the circulate of it:

app1.com --> 12.34.56.78 --> app1.example.com (so cloudflare servers) ---> 12.34.56.78 (return to origin server)

If I remove the proxy_ssl_server_name on; I get errors 421/403
And of course if I remove the proxy option from cloudflare then it also works without errors.
I can mitigate the load time by adding proxy_connect_timeout 3s; the failing requests are always being retried so this forcing them to be retried quicker.

I thought about using upstream but since I'm using passenger I don't really have a private ip + port for example.com:
# minimized version
server{
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    
    passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;


    ssl_certificate /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/deploy/domains/example.com.cert.combined;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/deploy/domains/example.com.key;
}


notice the errors are happening each time for different requests

To summary:
How can I use proxy_passto direct app1.com to app1.example.com (which proxied with cloudflare) when they both sits at the same server? Thank you
2024/04/04 21:24:43 [error] 885944#0: *17 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: <my_home_public_ip>, server: app1.com, request: "GET /assets/website-theme/transparent.png HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://[2a06:98c1:3121::7]:443/assets/website-theme/transparent.png", host: "app1.com", referrer: "https://app1.com/"

2024/04/04 21:24:43 [error] 885944#0: *17 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: <my_home_public_ip>, server: app1.com, request: "GET /cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://[2a06:98c1:3120::7]:443/cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js", host: "app1.com", referrer: "https://app1.com/"

2024/04/04 22:21:54 [error] 890667#0: *633 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: <my_home_public_ip>, server: app1.com, request: "GET /assets/website-theme/custom-colors/colour-blue-dark.min.css HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://[2a06:98c1:3120::7]:443/assets/website-theme/custom-colors/colour-blue-dark.min.css", host: "app1.com", referrer: "https://app1.com/"



I'm a bit confused, you use 443 without the ssl statement which belongs to my knowledgeable makes it to a simple http instead of https request. which would for myself declares why it gets confused

@djdomi It's a minimized version - I have the SSL, I'll update the question

if you still use listen 443 instead  listen 443 ssl it still makes them to http instead https

@djdomi it's listen 443  ssl http2;, updated question
